# How to use Constructor using getActivity()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

Hi I am working with android. I had created viewpager app using fragments, Now I wanted to add constructor in my adpter class. I used get Activity() instead of context, but it shows an error. How can I do this???

Here is my code:

my adapter.java

```
   public Swipe_adapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, String[] appname,
        String[] desc, int[] logo, int[] button, int[] rating) {
         this.context = getActivity();
          this.appname = appname;
          this.desc = desc;
          this.logo = logo;
          this.button = button;
          this.rating=rating;

   }
```

My Fragment class

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured, container, false);  

          appname = new String[] { "app1", "app2", "app3", "app4", "app5", "app6", "app7", "app8", "app9", "app10" };

              desc = new String[] { "ssddds", "sdsad", "sdsadsadsda",
                "Ijhgkhj", "ghghjghj", "ghjghjgh", "gjghjgh", "gjhghjgj",
                "ghjghjg64", "Juiououo" };
              logo = new int[] { R.drawable.app1, R.drawable.app2,
                R.drawable.app3, R.drawable.app4,
                R.drawable.app5, R.drawable.app6, R.drawable.app8,
                R.drawable.app1, R.drawable.app2, R.drawable.app3 };
               button = new int[] { R.drawable.download, R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.download, R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.download, R.drawable.download, R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.download, R.drawable.download, R.drawable.download };
               rating = new int[] { R.drawable.star, R.drawable.star,
                R.drawable.star, R.drawable.star,
                R.drawable.star, R.drawable.star, R.drawable.star,
                R.drawable.star, R.drawable.star, R.drawable.star };
          ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
           adapter = new Swipe_adapter(getActivity(), appname,desc,logo,button,rating);
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

          return rootView;
      }
     }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this.context = fragmentActivity;` instead of  `this.context = getActivity();` in adapter constructor

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() is a function defined in Fragment class. You cannot use that inside your adapter.

So you need to give your  fragmentActivity object as Context like

```
this.context= fragmentActivity;
```

Comment: your issue is fixed or still facing problems?